# Fibrin production from joint damage promotes arterial blockages?

Tags: heart-disease, cardiovascular-disease, cholesterol, joints, coronary-bypass

*Can increased fibrin production from joint damage **promote** vascular disease such as arterial blockages, particularly where obesity or markedly increased weight causes knee, hip, ankle, and spine damage?*

After realizing that fibrin can play a major role in vascular blockage construction or buildup, it also became evident that anything promoting increased fibrin production (such as your body's efforts to heal joints) may play a major role in contributing to traditional heart disease.  It would also go a long way in explaining why obesity itself is so problematic in arterial blockages to the heart.

Further, it would help to explain why cholesterol, by itself, does not so completely mark heart disease. For example, I would imagine that many of us, like me, know folks that have remarkably high cholesterol levels (even very high LDL), but never actually experience heart blockages. I have realized that many of these same people with longterm dangerously high LDL levels also are not (overly) obese, and particularly important to note, *did not experience serious joint troubles*.

However, conversely, I've witnessed person after person who has had problems with their knees, hips, back and such who consistently require stents or even open heart surgery to resolve blockages. I've also seen folks who've had minor joint problems require only a stent or two, and then suddenly when they required hip or knee replacement their blockage situation exploded and they required multiple bypasses.

While this is all anecdotal and seemingly clear via life examples, I'd be interested to see if any research has been done in this area yet to corroborate such data as I've not found anything that directly correlates this so far.

Comment: fibrin's role in blood clots is well known. You write as though everyone knows that when you have sore joints they make fibrin. Any links? Also, have you looked into the role of inflammation in vascular issues?

Comment: Fibrin production is triggered by joint damage and helps the healing process of said joints (similar to or perhaps the same as the role in blood clotting); when it's impeded rapidity of joint healing is also dramatically slowed. Interesting though, I'm sorry, I thought that this was well known and I'll have to dig up the research I read a while back that indicates this as I never thought to save the reference due to my assumption of it being readily known / available.

Comment: @KateGregory a couple of references, still hunting for the original, but these are fairly robust in their discussion & the image they paint re: joint repair, etc: [Textbook of Small Animal Orthopaedics, Ch4: _TENDONS, SKELETAL MUSCLES, AND LIGAMENTS IN HEALTH AND DISEASE_](http://cal.vet.upenn.edu/projects/saortho/chapter_04/04mast.htm) & [Sports Med (2017; 47, Suppl 1): _Minimizing Injury and Maximizing Return to Play: Lessons
from Engineered Ligaments_](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/55b7ffebe4b0568a75e3316b/t/59c2d959d2b8571382750f1a/1505941861147/Baar+2017+%28Eng+Ligament%29.pdf)